# C# - Check URL is valid for TemplateString

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm currently using a TemplateString to load an image with a link, where {Url} is the file name obtained from the database.

Here is the code I use, as a reference:

```
Ext.Net.TemplateColumn TheColumn = new Ext.Net.TemplateColumn();
TheColumn.Text = "Image";
TheColumn.DataIndex = "Url";
TheColumn.Align = Alignment.Center;
TheColumn.Flex = 1;
TheColumn.MinWidth = 70;
TheColumn.TemplateString = "<a href='http://example.com/{Url}' data-lightbox='{Url}'><img style='width:60px;height:60px;' src='http://example.com/{Url}'/></a>";
```

What I would like to do is that I could check if the requested image exists, and if it doesn't, I use an alternative TemplateString instead.

Since I'm using jQuery, I´m leaving the tag in case. The project is an ASP.NET website.

Comment: So you need to make a web request and see what is returned, have you tried implemeting it?

Comment: You can call the head as a response as a Web Request to check if url exist by checking the status code of the response.

Comment: I tried a few alternatives using HttpWebRequest, however it doesn't work as it gets {Url} (as a string rather a value).

Comment: For the moment I decided to use an .htaccess on the directory so it redirects to an error image, however I´d prefer to implement it on the code instead.